# Why when I change a TextField in a custom cell, another text Field in another cell is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a TableView with custom cell in each cell I have a text field, when I change the value of the textField, another text field in another cell is changed.

Exemple :

I changed the value in cell 0, cell 8 has also changed

**tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath Method**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Disbursment_CustomCell";

Disbursment_CustomCell *cell = (Disbursment_CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[Disbursment_CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

}

 cell.disbursmentNumber_label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",[indexPath row]];
return cell;
}
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
@implementation Disbursment_CustomCell
@synthesize dateDisbursment_textField,pourcentage_Slider,pourcentage_textField;
-(IBAction) sliderChanged:(id) sender{
      self.pourcentage_textField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", lroundf(self.pourcentage_Slider.value)];
}
- (void)handlePickerChanged:(id)sender
{
   UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker *)sender;
NSDate *myDate = picker.date;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"];
NSString *prettyVersion = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];
self.dateDisbursment_textField.text = prettyVersion;
}
- (IBAction)didBegin:(id)sender {

self.picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[self.picker addTarget:self action:@selector(handlePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
dateDisbursment_textField.inputView = self.picker ;
}

@end
```

Comment: can u please show me your - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method??

Comment: use `textfield delegate` methods and reload particular cell .

Comment: is cell 8 visible on screen or when you scroll down you see that it's changed?

Comment: Show your code in your  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. so one can better understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Put a breakpoint next to all three instances of `cell.disbursmentNumber_label.text =`. One of them is getting called when you don't want it to. Either this or it's a problem with recycling of the cells - but since you are rewriting the text in every run (not just some), I don't think that will turn out to be the problem. Put the breakpoints in and watch for unintentional rewrites.

Comment: as @Desdenova said,  your cells are being reused, thats when a cell is reused you see the old values in the text field. How many textfields do you have in your table?

Comment: Cell 8 is not visible on screen,

Comment: for each cell I have 3 textfield, cell 8 is not visible in the screen, when i scrool down i see the value, I put breakpoint, it executes the method sliderChanged 3 times to change 3 text Filed or more ...

Answer (score 0):

This question might be old but for people like myself who are having the same issue, here is my solution:

I got a hint from one of the comments above saying the cell is being reused. This is the case. One can then find the `prepareForReuse` method as part of the UITableViewCell class. using this method (after you call `super.prepareForReuse()`) you can insert some lines which set the text labels back to their defaults. Any cell being reused will jump back to default then. Think of this method as a `viewDidLoad` type of thing, but for cells which are being reused - ones that are not currently on the screen...

NOTE: I must point out that once you scroll down and back up in your table view, those cells are being recreated using the reuse identifier. So if you make a change to one, then scroll down a little, then back up so the cell shows on the screen again, it will do whats inside the `prepareForReuse` method... So try keep track of a cell identity or something (I used an array which contained the id's of the cells changed).

As it stands, this i the best I have found. If I find something better I will edit my answer.

My Code for the `prepareForReuse` method:

```
override func prepareForReuse()
{
    super.prepareForReuse()
    if findInArray("\(stopName)\(routeNumber)\(lblTime.text)") == true
    {
        btnNotification.setTitle("☗", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    else
    {
        btnNotification.setTitle("☖", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```